# Why does my generic linkedlist get this error?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I can't see why this code is not working, I believe I am using generics correctly but the method is apparently not defined? node and linkedlist classes are completely generic and I am creating a node of different types (eg semicircle) that share the same abstract superclass PlanarShape and trying to add them to an instantiated linklist of that type.

Relevant part of main class

```
 LinkedList<PlanarShape> plygns = new LinkedList<PlanarShape>();

 Point p0 = new Point(Double.parseDouble(sc.next()), Double.parseDouble(sc.next()));
 Point p1 = new Point(Double.parseDouble(sc.next()), Double.parseDouble(sc.next()));

 SemiCircle smc = new SemiCircle(p0, p1);
 plygns.prepend(new Node<SemiCircle>(smc));
```

prepend is getting the error prepend(Node) is undefined for the type Linkedlist

Linkedlist method prepend

```
public void prepend(Node<T> n) //add to head
{
   //Empty until error fixed
}
```

Comment: Do you have your own type `Linkedlist`? Java is case sensitive. And there is already `java.util.LinkedList` (which does not have such a method).

Comment: So I can't create my own LinkedList class and just not include the java one?

Comment: You **can**, but we can't tell which one you are using here; or the capitalization of your version. This is not a reproducible example.

Comment: LinkedList is my own class, should I rename it to linkedList or something?

Comment: Try `MyLinkedList` if you must write your own; otherwise, use `java.util.LinkedList` (but that's probably not the actual problem) - you should **edit** your question into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of PlanarShapes and you're trying to "prepend" a Node with type SemiCircle. With the way you have written prepend, it will accept Nodes with type `PlanarShape` **only**.

Assuming `SemiCircle` is a subtype of `PlanarShape`, you'll need to change prepend to allow subtypes of T with a "wildcard":

```
public void prepend(Node<? extends T> n) {
   ...
}
```